# Preventing OnActionExecuting and filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this filter class.

```
 public class Sessional : ActionFilterAttribute
    {    
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            LoggedUserInfo user = (LoggedUserInfo)session["User"];

            if ((user == null && !session.IsNewSession) || (session.IsNewSession))
            {
                UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                string loginUrl = urlHelper.Content("~/Account/LogOut");
                FAuth.AbandonSession();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I apply it on the Controller, all the action will logout user if session is unavailable.
But I want to write attribute that allow the only action to do its work without loggin out, for example UnSessional.

```
 [Authorize] 
    [Sessional]
    public class ReportController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet] 
        [UnSessional]
        public ActionResult GetReport() //unsessional action
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetReport(GetReportModel model) //sessional action
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the "UnSessionAttribute" existance for the current Action, here is the sample code:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UnSessionAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            {
                  return;
            }

            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            LoggedUserInfo user = (LoggedUserInfo)session["User"];

            if ((user == null && !session.IsNewSession) || (session.IsNewSession))
            {
                UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                string loginUrl = urlHelper.Content("~/Account/LogOut");
                FAuth.AbandonSession();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
            }
        }
```